# Differential Microstrip Impedance Calculators Giving Conflicting Answers

Tags: pcb, impedance, differential

I am attempting to determine the trace width needed for routing a differential signal of 100 Ω on a PCB I am designing.

This is a hobby project and the differential traces are for gigabit ethernet.

I'm very tempted to just forget about it, and just go with that manufacturer's numbers, but I am curious why different calculators spit out such wildly different numbers.

I found some EE exchange posts which provided unsatisfactory answers:

[Link1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57093/huge-variation-of-impedance-calculators-with-same-parameters) [Link2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/417159/microstrip-transmission-line-impedance-calculation)

The second link seems to hint that some calculators take some extra parameters into consideration.

Having never routed differential signals the size difference these calculators are coming up with is a little alarming  but perhaps this is normal?

Parameters:

1. Trace Separation: 4mil
2. Trace thickness: 1.4mil
3. Dielectric Thickness: 3.5mil
4. Er: 4.05

The manufacturer provides a stack up as well as a 2D calculator for determining trace width: [here](https://cart.jlcpcb.com/impedanceCalculation)
The manufacture's calculator computes 3.49mil trace width.

When I attempted to validate this against other online calculators I find that some agree and some differ substantially.

[EEWeb](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/edge-coupled-microstrip-impedance/): Says the same numbers from my manufacture would be 160ohms!

[Everythingrf](https://www.everythingrf.com/rf-calculators/differential-microstrip-impedance-calculator): Agrees with the manufacture.

Can someone explain why they are different and what I need to consider when deciding trace width using these tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JLCPCB and EverythingRF use the same formula which **only** applies to circumstances where the trace-width-to-dielectric-thickness ratio is less than 1 (W/H < 1).

<sup>*(EEWeb has a good explanation on their webpage but I didn't check if they use the same formula)*.</sup>

In your case the ratio is quite close 1: Trace width (W) is 3.49 mil, and dielectric thickness (H) is 3.5 mil. The ratio goes beyond 1 as the separation gets higher. So if you find that the dielectric thickness is less than or equal to the required trace width then you should review the stack-up.

JLCPCB's first stack-up recommendation for 1.6mm PCB seems correct to me but the 2nd one doesn't.

Comment: When you say the first and 2nd one do you you mean  JLC7628 Stackup vs  JLC2313 Stackup?